# Are there any ways to sync mempool from another nodes faster?

Tags: mempool

I still use bitcoin 0.13.2 for some reasons. Recent mempool size is very high so syncing mempool takes for a long time, over two days. Are there any ways to sync mempool faster? I have some bitcoind nodes. Some of them have already finished to sync full mempool. I hope I can copy mempool from my another nodes.

Comment: are you asking about syncing mempool or syncing blockchain?

Comment: Hi, asking about syncing mempool.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where I restarted my bitcoin node for changing some parameters and it took half a day to catch upto to all uncomfirmed tx. Bitcoin 0.14 has a feature that stores current mempool to disk and loads it back on startup https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/8448. It should be possible to copy mempool.dat files to your other nodes that are behind.

Comment: yes, I really want to change to v0.14. But I cannot now..

Answer (score 1):

As dark knight stated, [Bitcoin Core 0.14.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.14.0) brought us the feature of persisting the mempool over restarts of Core. I've been also hearing some rumors that there's improved set reconciliation for mempools in the work by some Core developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are searching for:

https://github.com/dev7ba/mempoolcp